# Why am I getting Buffer Overflow? How can I avoid it? [C++]

Tags: c++, csv, buffer, buffer-overflow

**Introduction:**

Hi all, I have a `.csv` file that contains (x, y, z) coordinates of an image with a resolution of 1280x720 (width x height). In these datapoints, it contains the z value which represents depth for that particular pixel. There are 1280x720 = 921,600 points in the CSV file.

[image: CSV File: Last Row Last Column]

**Problem:**

Initially, I wanted to copy these 921,600 points in a 2D array to my own program for processing. I wrote `double Array2D[1280][720];` but the program crashed, most probably because of Stack Overflow. My other new method almost works, but also seemed to experience a similar issue, is it Buffer Overflow?

In my own testing of the code below, querying (x, y) from points (0, 0) to (1279, 565) works, but anything after 565 is invalid. For example, in the .CSV file, at point (1279, 565), the actual value is 1.589, which my program manages to get. At point (1279, 566), the actual value is 1.579, but my program returns a 0 value.

[image: Console Test Program]

Is this a Buffer Overflow of some sort? What can I do to fix this?

**CSV File:**
[Link to .CSV File](https://github.com/HippoEug/CPP_Functions/blob/master/ReadCSV/test.csv_Depth_3068.csv)

**Full-Simplified Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <class T, size_t W, size_t H>
class Array2D {
public:
    const int width = W;
    const int height = H;
    typedef typename T type;

    Array2D() {
        buffer.resize(width*height);
    }

    T &operator() (int x, int y) {
        return buffer[y*width + x];
    }

    const T &operator() (int x, int y) const {
        return buffer[y*width + x];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> buffer;
};

int main() {
    char eater; // Charater to remove ',' and '\n' in a .CSV file
    int xs, ys; // User queried points, X & Y coordinates

    Array2D<double, 1281, 721> a;

    // Opening (x, y, z) .CSV file with 921,600 points
    std::ifstream coordinatesFile;
    coordinatesFile.open("test2.csv_Depth_3068.csv");

    std::cout << "COPYING" << std::endl;

    // Copying the z(depth) data into a Vector
    for (int y = 1; y < 720; y++) { // Iterating through 720 rows
        for (int x = 1; x < 1280; x++) { // Iterating through 1280 columns
            coordinatesFile >> a(x, y); // Copying the value with X, Y coordinates
            coordinatesFile >> eater; // Remove the ',' after each z(depth) value
        }
        coordinatesFile >> eater; // Removes the '\n' after every row in a .CSV file, should run 720 times since there are 720 rows which means there are 720 '\n's
    }

    // For user to Query the data stored in vector
    while (1) {
        std::cout << "Enter X val: ";
        std::cin >> xs;
        std::cout << "Enter Y val: ";
        std::cin >> ys;

        std::cout << "Value = " << a(xs, ys) << std::endl;
    }

    coordinatesFile.close();
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: `for (int y = 1; y < 720; y++)` - shouldn't that be `for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++)`, and `x = 0; x < 1280` on the next line.

Comment: I'd rather guess there is some error in the CSV file. You should check `cin` after each read - once it has its `fail` bit set, it won't read further any more without having (explicitly) cleared it.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `Array2D<double, 1281, 721> a;` be `Array2D<double, 1280, 720> a;`?

Comment: @KenY-N the moment I change to `for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++)`, I break the code because of how the `.CSV` is formatted. Every 1280 columns/data points, after the last value in a row, instead of having a comma, it has a `\n` instead. I wrote it in my version to simplify it.

Comment: First you need to narrow down the problem -- is there a problem reading the file?  Saving the values in the array?  Retrieving them afterwards?  Do you have a debugger?  What have you done so far to debug this ('debugging' doesn't mean changing things in the program and seeing if it then works.  It means gathering information about what is and is not happening and reaching an understanding (or, an attempt at understanding) what is wrong.  Then fixing and testing.

Comment: Your code purports to read `number` `comma` `number` `comma` ... `number` `comma` `newline`. However, if you look at your `CSV` file, you will see the format does not match. In fact, your recent comment says as much.

Comment: By the way: the '\n' character is whitespace; it should be ignored on reading the next double anyway, so you shouldn't *need* to consume it explicitly...

Comment: A general (safe but slower) algorithm to read input is to read it in chunks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays (and `std::vector`s) have valid indexes from `0` to `size - 1`.

Also not sure why you define

> ```
> Array2D<double, 1281, 721> a;
> ```

Use:

```
Array2D<double, 1280, 720> a;
```

and

```
for (int y{}; y < 720; ++y) {
    for (int x{}; x < 1280; ++x) {
        if (!(coordinatesFile >> a(x, y) >> std::noskipws >> eater >> std::skipws)
            && !coordinatesFile.eof() && eater != ',' && eater != '\n')
        {
            std::cerr << "Format error at " << x + 1 << '/' << y + 1 << " :(\n\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Yea, I was trying different things. But I think ultimately the bigger problem is why anything after (1280, 565) is invalid even though I defined the Vector size to be (1281, 721)

Comment: wow it works! Are you able to briefly clarify why does pre-increment fix my particular issue? And also why is `std::noskipws` required? I do not see any whitespaces between any values and coma?

Comment: @HippoEug Fixing it has nothing to do with pre- or post-increment. `std::noskipws` is required so the eater also reads the newline (`'\n'`) at the end of a line and does not consume the first digit of the first double in the next line instead.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer, but `int y{}` is IMO an ugly way to initialise to zero.

Comment: @KenY-N it almost looks like `0` ;)